# Extract non common areas between rasters in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I'm trying to extract the non common areas between two rasters in R.

I have two rasters: yellow and red.

I want to extract all the points of the yellow that DO NOT overlap with red (i.e. all the yellow you see in the plot below).

I tried with the raster package but I got this error:

```
mask(crop(yellow, red), red)

Error in compareRaster(x, mask) : different extent
```

Here the extents:

```
extent(yellow)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 16.96877 
xmax       : 28.91172 
ymin       : 40.81715 
ymax       : 48.22444 

extent(red)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 16.74428 
xmax       : 28.91172 
ymin       : 40.23355 
ymax       : 48.89783
```

[image]

Comment: The raster do not have matching geometries. That can be fixed, but you need to add to your question what is returned by `show(red)` and `show(yellow)` to best suggest how that can be done. It is probably also useful to report how you created these rasters in the first place (if you created them, they can ensure that they match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the **mask()** function with the argument **inverse == TRUE**
See: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.5-15/topics/mask